# Ошибка авторизации в боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Бот при запуске выдает ошибку

```
    (venv) root@ggprom:~/get_sms_tg_bot# python3 main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 1195, in <module>
        start_bot()
      File "main.py", line 1038, in start_bot
        numberrs_buy(start)
      File "main.py", line 954, in numberrs_buy
        func.admin_rass(textt)
      File "/root/get_sms_tg_bot/functions.py", line 459, in admin_rass
        rassilka.send_message(1462109040, user_id)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 735, in send_message
        reply_markup, parse_mode, disable_notification, timeout))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 206, in send_message
        return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 113, in _make_request
        json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 140, in _check_result
        raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
    telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized
```

Из ошибки можно сделать вывод что токен не верный, однако при веб запросе ответ положительный

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":1559818692,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"SMS","username":"get_sms_tg_bot","can_join_groups":true,"can_read_all_group_messages":false,"supports_inline_queries":false}}
```

Весь код вставить не могу, вот начало и конец

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3
import menu
import settings
import functions as func
import telebot
from telebot import types, apihelper
import time
import datetime
import random
import threading
import config
import traceback

buy_dict = {}
balance_dict = {}
admin_sending_messages_dict = {}
product_dict = {}
download_dict = {}

def start_bot():
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token='1559818692:AAGb14vs4vP1SqJ-n9WIABd2QXvs9l8wfRM', threaded=True,                 num_threads=300)
    #apihelper.proxy = {"https": "socks5://178.165.44.122:1080"}

# *тут функции, пропустим лишнее*

    threading.Thread(target=sending_check).start()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

start_bot()
```

Comment: убедительная просьба вставлять код/ошибки в вопрос текстом. По фотографии невсегда удобно читать

Comment: @DGDays, исправил

Comment: Вы зарегистрировали своего бота через Bot Father-а в телеграмме?

Comment: Да, конечно. Также пробовал revoke token - бесполезно(

Comment: Говорят, что можно попробовать отозвать токен бота и использовать новый иногда решает проблему -_-

Comment: С другими ботами аналогично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, эта строка:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(
    token='1559818692:AAGb14vs4vP1SqJn9WIABd2QXvs9l8wfRM', 
    threaded=True,
    num_threads=300)
```

должна быть глобальной; во-вторых вы должны прописывать `bot.polling()` вне функции.

Пример:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(
    token='1559818692:AAGb14vs4vP1SqJn9WIABd2QXvs9l8wfRM',
    threaded=True,
    num_threads=300)

--Тут все функции--

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```